# Logging issue in Wildfly server with JDK11 setup

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, slf4j

Facing issue related to logging in Wildfly deployment of Java web application.
Wildfly version used: **wildfly-15**.0.0

The web application is having a **Spring MVC** configuration. Spring framework version is **4.3.1** and logging is configured using **logback.xml** with **slf4j**.
Applications' *JDK compliance level is 1.8* and it is set up to run on JDK11 on Wildfly.

The application logs are being printed in wildfly server logs. It should get printed in the file provided in the application's logback.xml

Below are the *Jars added for logging* into the application's WEB-INF/lib folder.

- log4j-1.2.16.jar
- log4j-api-2.11.2.jar
- log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar
- logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
- logback-core-1.2.3.jar

Tried *adding a module* in the Wildfly server under $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/ but it didn't work.

Also added the following configuration to the subsytem "urn:jboss:domain:logging:6.0 in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

After this, the application logs are printed at the proper location. However, the *logs inside of the application's custom jars aren't getting print*. Neither in server logs nor in application logs.

The same configuration is working as expected in tomcat 9. But it seems like the logback.xml is not being bootstrapped properly in Wildfly.
Any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: Why do you have both logback and log4j dependency in your WAR?

Comment: @KarlAlexander That doesn't make any difference in this scenario, tried removing the log4j dependencies but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

By default WildFly has it's own slf4j binding which writes to the servers log manager. If you'd like to use your own log manager you need to do one of the following.

- Exclude the logging subsystem from your deployment in a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`
- Exclude the logging dependencies you want to provide yourself, in your case it looks like `org.slf4j.api`, `org.slf4j.impl` and `org.apache.log4j` in a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`
- Change the logging subsystem attribute `add-logging-api-dependencies` to `false`.

For more details have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/23/Admin_Guide.html#how-do-i-use-log4j.properties-or-log4j.xml-instead-of-using-the-logging-subsystem-configuration). Note the [per-deployment logging](https://docs.wildfly.org/23/Admin_Guide.html#how-do-i-use-log4j.properties-or-log4j.xml-instead-of-using-the-logging-subsystem-configuration) link seems to be broken there which we will get fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Just to update, First two didn't work.
I have already tried adding the logging subsystem attribute add-logging-api-dependencies to false, after this change the logs inside of the application's custom jars aren't getting print. 
e.g. ProjectA has a jar named 'projectB.jar' in /WEB-INF/lib, then the logs of 'projectB.jar' aren't print anywhere.

Comment: What logging frameworks/facades are you using? You seem to have a mix of log4j, log4j2 and slf4j. What is `projectB.jar` using?

Comment: slf4j is used as a logging framework in the main application (projectA.war) as well as in custom jar (projectB.jar)

Comment: As long as you exclude the logging dependencies in one way or another that should work with no problem. If it's not working you might have some weird slf4j binding issue in your deployment. It's not really easy to say what the issue might be without knowing a lot more about the application.